# Eigen: sparse matrices computing sum of all elements in a row

Tags: c++, math, sparse-matrix, eigen

I'm using the Eigen library to work with sparse matrices and I need to process a matrix, i.e. to:

- divide every row of a sparse matrix by the sum of all elements in that row `+1` (the extra `1` is added to avoid dividing by zero).

I have a hunch that iterating through the rows, then computing the element sum for each row using yet another iteration will be very inefficient.

To illustrate what I need, let's consider this naive (dense example):

```
input: J = [ 1, 5; 3, 9];
output: Jp = [0.1666, 0.8333; 0.25, 0.75];
```

Could you provide a faster/cheaper solution for this process?

Comment: You'll need to iterate each row twice, no way around that...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation..